# Using greater-than or equal/less-than or equal twice in one SQL query

Tags: sql, search, comparison-operators

I'm trying to create what is basically a timestamp search query. The user puts in a beginning time and end time for a desired reservation and the search finds any current reservations for that room during that time period. If a match is found, the user is told that the room is already reserved.

The problem I'm running into is that when I send this query:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE begintime <= '$start' AND endtime >= '$end' AND room = '$room';
```

I get no records. The variables are holding the right information, so I suspect that the way I'm using the arithmetic operators is wrong. I've looked around plenty and found many examples of both types of comparisons being used in one query, but only for one column. I haven't found any examples of someone comparing a value against one column and a value against another column like this all in one query.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: I have the timestamp set in Epoch time, so the start time put into the search will either be greater than or equal to what is already in the database to fall between the start and end time. Inverse goes for the end time, as the time put into the search will either be less than or equal to the end time in the database to fall between the start and end time. Flipping the signs would find times outside the reservation in the database. Inputs are validated.

Comment: It seems this question has nothing to do with PHP as it's apparently belongs to SQL only. You may wish to change the code to pure SQL also

Comment: Correct. I think he got his comparision operators wrong, as in my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find that you have different scenarios:

- A reservation starts in your search-period
- A reservation ends in you
  search-period
- A reservation starts before you search-period and ends
  after it.

You have to search all three

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE ((begintime <= '$start' AND endtime >= '$end') OR (begintime >= '$start' AND endtime <= '$start')  OR (begintime >= '$end' AND endtime <= '$end')) AND room = '$room';
```

Comment: I see where you were going with that and you are correct conceptually. That query still returns nothing, though. I will tool with it a bit.

Comment: The query is just written out of my head, just play a little around with it and use a big interval of $start and $end where you are 100% sure that there have to be entries (look in the table!). Then try a $start and $end for all three scenarios.

Comment: This works:

"SELECT * FROM event WHERE ((begintime <= $start AND endtime >= $end) OR (begintime >= $start AND endtime <= $end) OR (begintime <= $start AND endtime <= $end) OR (begintime >= $start AND endtime >= $end)) AND room = '$room'";

Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: You have a mistake in your Query!The last both conditions arent working.Say you are search for (1.12 - 3.12)and in your Database is an entry (4.12 - 5.12). Now in your fourth condition your checking for 'begintime > $start' (4.12 > 1.12 TRUE) and 'endtime > $end' (5.12 > 3.12 TRUE). I understand what you were thinking, but this will also find reservations that start after your searched Interval. Same as the third condition will find all entries beginning and ending prior to your searched interval.As in your comment the apostrophes are missing, maybe this was the problem with my original query.

Comment: Yeah, I discovered that a couple of days ago. Complete absent-mindedness on my part. This is the fully working query: 

SELECT * FROM event WHERE ((begintime <= $start AND endtime >= $end) OR (begintime >= $start AND endtime <= $end) OR (begintime <= $start AND endtime <= $end AND endtime >= $start) OR (begintime >= $start AND endtime >= $end AND begintime <= $end)) AND room = '$room';

Answer (score 0):

You should switch them, I gues?

Here it is:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE begintime >= '$start' AND endtime <= '$end' AND room = '$room';
```

You need a begin time after start date and before end date.
Plus - you may want to validate if your begin and end variables comply to the following:

1. They are either equal (in worst case)
   **OR**
2. begintime is less than endtime.

Otherwise you are not guaranteed to receive any results.

Comment: I have the timestamp set in Epoch time, so the start time put into the search will either be greater than or equal to what is already in the database to fall between the start and end time. Inverse goes for the end time, as the time put into the search will either be less than or equal to the end time in the database to fall between the start and end time. Flipping the signs would find times outside the reservation in the database. Inputs are validated.

Comment: you both are describing different scenario, one where you look for reservations that start and and in your interval, and one where you look for reservations that start before and end after the interval. See my answer for details

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the post, `$start` and `$end` are the inputs from the user.

In that case you should write the query as:

```
SELECT * FROM event WHERE begintime >= '$start' AND endtime <= '$end' AND room = '$room';
```

The condtions are put in reverse order.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM event 
 WHERE CASE 
          WHEN begintime > '$start' THEN begintime 
          ELSE '$start' 
       END
       <
       CASE 
          WHEN endtime > '$end' THEN '$end'
          ELSE endtime 
       END
       AND room = '$room';
```